# Loading audio for Web Audio API use in the most memory efficient manner

Tags: out-of-memory, html5-audio, audio-streaming, webrtc, web-audio-api

I have an application that loads ~15 1+ MB AAC audio files and then plays them repeatedly on demand. On desktop browsers it works fine, but on Mobile Safari it reliably crashes because of memory issues:

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
OS Version:          iPhone OS 7.1 (11D167)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Feb 21 19:33:46 PST 2014; root:xnu-2423.10.67~1/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8950X
Date:                2014-05-14 09:36:33 -0400
Time since snapshot: 263 ms

Free pages:                              2299
Active pages:                            10722
Inactive pages:                          4853
Speculative pages:                       804
Throttled pages:                         215798
Purgeable pages:                         0
Wired pages:                             25998
File-backed pages:                       11493
Anonymous pages:                         4886
Compressions:                            3160361
Decompressions:                          1482836
Compressor Size:                         181
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        310
Largest process:   MobileSafari

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max   fds      [reason]          (state)

      librariand <uuid>          369              369  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (daemon)
     MobilePhone <uuid>         5793             5793  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (continuous)
    MobileSafari <uuid>       163511           163511  200   [vm-pageshortage]  (audio) (frontmost) (resume)
    ...
```

Currently I am loading the audio files using a sample [BufferLoader.js](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/doc/loading-sounds.html) script that loads them via AJAX into `ArrayBuffer`s and then creates `AudioBufferSourceNode`s:

```
var source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = bufferList[0];
```

This obviously doesn't perform well with more than a few files, especially as I keep the raw buffers around to create and play sources on demand.

I see several similar alternatives. I could:

- Create `audio` elements and then create `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`s from them.
- Create `audio` elements, then create `MediaStream`s from them, and finally create `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`s from those.
- Somehow get `FileReader` references to the files and then get those into a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`s.

Are these accurate summaries of my options? Which would let me download the audio files the fewest times but keep the smallest amount of data in memory at any time (versus in Mobile Safari's file cache)?

Thanks!

Comment: So you still want to have all the AAC files on the client, but not have them all converted to ArrayBuffers? You could use audio elements for that. Note that when getting a file(local) or blob (data got through xhr, but can also be from a local file) you can use object URL's to refer to this and play it using audio elements. You can also save the files to the [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) so each time the user opens your webpage the files are still there.

Comment: Doing some researching, localStorage only accepts strings (put 151 MB in strings isn't great), and the FileSystem API is deprecated since a month, as hardly any browser implemented it. You can also work with the caching of files. That should work perfectly. I can help you with that if you think that is the right solution for this.

Comment: I think just using `var audio = new Audio(); audio.load();` will be the best best for me.

Comment: that is the best solution. If you add a manifest file, the browser downloads all the files and saves them to the cache. Whenever you update the manifest file server side, the files get redownloaded. More information [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner). I suggest you to read that document. It decreases the loading of files to one time, and you can just use the normal URLs as src in the audio element.

Answer (score 1):

To put my comment in an answer:

When using `Audio` elements, you can easily use the src to the file stored on the server. Now you might not want the client to download the files every time. In that case, add a manifest file location to your html tag:

```
<html manifest="link/to/file">
```

The first time the browser loads the page, it recoginizes it and downloads the manifest file. I then reads the file to find out whether it has to download and store files or redownload files every time. Every time the page is loaded, the browser checks if there is any difference between the local manifest file and the server one. When it is, the user has to reload the page, but you can also do this manually with a simple script (suggest to add this to the html document and not any of the script files it has to load):

```
applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {if(applicationCache.status == 4) location.reload();});
```

Now the contents of the manifest file itself. Add `CACHE MANIFEST` on top, and below you can dump all the URL's that need to be chached. If you want to add files it shall explicitly load every time, you need to declare something more. Add `CACHE:` and below all the files you want to cache, and `NETWORK:` to let the page know it has to redownload the files every time.

Using this system, you do not only guarantee speed and decreased network load, but also a webpage that is useable offline. If there is something the page needs to load every time (like some update document), you can add `FALLBACK:` in your document. Whenever the specified file is not available it uses another file you have chosen:

```
FALLBACK:
/file/to/load /path/to/file/if/other/file/is/unavailable
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: The files to load are determined dynamically based upon a data file, so the manifest file would only help if I can programmatically insert files into the manifest and the browser will immediately in the current session respect the caching commands.

Comment: Otherwise, the server returning an `ETag` or `Last-Modified` header should be enough to queue up the normal browser caching, no?

Comment: @pr1001 It should do that with ETags, yes.